# cant install Adam from keras.optimizer

Tags: python, keras

Was working on google colab yesterday and everything works fine. but now I got a problem when trying to import Adam.

this is what I try to import

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
```

this is what I got

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-36a1fe725448> in <module>()
     30 from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
     31 from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling2D
---> 32 from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop

ImportError: cannot import name 'Adam' from 'keras.optimizers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Comment: Keras seems to be broken again in Colab, its using version 2.6, maybe you can downgrade it to a version that works, or not use Colab since you do not have full control on software versions.

Answer (score 7):

Try to import from `tf.keras` as follows

```py
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Adam optimizer function using TensorFlow:

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam